# QP (Quantum Platform) Statecharts with Eclipse rather than QM

Tags: eclipse, uml, state-machine, papyrus

Miro Samek's QM graphical modeling tool (http://www.state-machine.com/qm/) seems like a good tool for semi graphical editing of UML statecharts for the QP framework. I would however like to use eclipse papyrus for this task because I have some experience with it.

Does anyone feel in a position to compare papyrus to QM?

Can anyone point me to good literature on code generation from statecharts made with papyrus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never used Papyrus, but I just went through a tutorial for it.

The biggest difference that I see is that Papyrus appears to be primarily a UML modeling tool. Code generation is a "side-component" (The exact term from the penultimate page of [A slide-ware tutorial on Papyrus usage for starters (2010-10-01)](http://www.eclipse.org/modeling/mdt/papyrus/usersTutorials/resources/TutorialOnPapyrusUSE_d20101001.pdf).) Here's a [StackOverflow question about code generation with Papyrus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7130937/how-to-generate-code-by-papyrus-on-eclipse)... it sounds complicated.  I browsed Papyrus' forum and tutorials and didn't find anything immediately helpful related to code generation.

UML is traditionally considered a design phase technology in the Waterfall software development process, so once software is modeled in UML, implementation is a separate process.  Not so with QM.

QM, unlike Papyrus, is not a general UML modeling tool; it's for modeling UML Statecharts with the sole purpose of compiling them, within the tool, to traceable C or C++ code.  As you know, QM is related to QP, a state machine framework.  QM builds code that utilizes QP.

QM's is your modeller and IDE.  Your final source code, barring external libraries, is 100% generated by QM.  As you graphically develop your UML Statecharts, you're expected to write C or C++ code that runs on transitions to/from your states.  When you compile, QM combines your written code with its own generated code to produce a source files that you can compile immediately without making any additional changes.